# Save Screenshot into Internal Storage and Sync into Gallery?

Tags: android, android-internal-storage

I have searched high and low for a way to do this and the best I could find involved saving the screenshot into the SD Card. What I want to do instead is to `onclick()`, take a screenshot of the current activity and saves it in the internal storage so that the user can view it in their gallery as and when they want.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is harder to post a whole code in here. I think you should follow some tutorials.

According to the your requirement what I got is, You need to take a screenshot using an your application and it should be stored in device SD card.

For that you should add proper permission to the manifest first,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and add following code to the activity:

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file, you can change it to your path
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this code will open the generated image(screenshot):

```
private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is how I did for my project. Sometimes this might be not satisfied for you requirement. It it is not satisfied, please follow these tutorials, **Thanks**

**Reference List** : http://www.androhub.com/take-a-screenshot-programmatically-in-android/

http://devdeeds.com/take-screenshot-programmatically/

https://www.viralandroid.com/2016/01/how-to-take-screenshot-programmatically-in-android.html

if you want to check whether SD card is available or not. here is the way. If SD card is not available then you can use internal storage to store the image.

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
Boolean isSDSupportedDevice = Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable();

if(isSDSupportedDevice && isSDPresent)
{
  // yes SD-card is present
}
else
{
 // SD-card not available 
}
```

Comment: this is great but I'm actually looking to save it in internal storage. I have been able to do it if it's in SD card previously but the issue I had was that not everyone has an SD card

Comment: Then check whether SD-Card is present or not. If present you can use it to store the image, If not use internal storage. Check my answer now. Thanks.